# Recover named features from L1 regularized logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following pipeline:

```
sg = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),                                                                                                                                            
               ('normalize', Normalizer()),                                                                                                                                                 
               ('l1', LogisticRegression(penalty="l1", dual=False))])
```

and after peforming the fitting, I want to extract the tokens that correnponds
to the non-zero weights.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is "tokens"? Column names of pandas data frame? or what are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
features = pipeline.named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names()
print(features[pipeline.named_steps['l1'].coef_ != 0])
```

See [TfidfTransformer docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer), [LogisticRegression docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) and the [unmerged improved pipeline docs here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4486/files)